# Chrome autofill repopulates input when field is deleted

Tags: google-chrome, redux, redux-form, autofill, preact

Chrome autofill repopulates email/password inputs when fields are deleted preventing the user from being able to log in using a different email/password. Have tried removing our original form implementation and using redux-form however still get the same issue. Has anyone experienced this issue?

[image]

Version
"preact": "8.2.5",
"redux": "3.7.2",
"react": "^15.4.2",

Chrome 65.0.3325.181

Component:

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';

import { Form } from '../form';
import { SubmitButton } from '../../buttons';
import styles from './create-account.styl';

export const CreateAccount = (props) => {
    const {
        canSubmit,
        onFormSubmit,
    } = props;

    return (
        <Form
            class={styles.root}
            heading="Heading"
            onSubmit={onFormSubmit}
        >
            <Field
                class={styles.field}
                name="email"
                component="input"
                type="email"
            />

            <Field
                class={styles.field}
                name="password"
                component="input"
                type="password"
            />

            <div class={styles.actions}>
                <SubmitButton
                    class={styles.submit}
                    disabled={!canSubmit}
                >
                    Submit
                </SubmitButton>
            </div>
        </Form>
    );
};
```

Container:

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { CreateAccount } from './create-account';

const enhance = compose(
    reduxForm({
        form: 'test',
    }),
);

export default enhance(CreateAccount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem before.
I solved this problem by following someone's advice(sorry, I don't remember link).
Please try to add following input fields at first of form.

```
<input type="email" name="email1" style={{display: 'none'}} />
<input type="password" name="password1" style={{display:'none'}} />
```

Please let me know if you have a problem still

Comment: I've tried this but had still had the same problem. For now I'm adding autocomplete="new-password" to all password fields. This disables the autofill functionality for the email field directly above. Still getting strange behaviour on other fields. Chrome is adding email and passwords into other fields such as first name and search. I've followed Chromes docs for correct autocomplete field names and still get the same issue.

Comment: You have to use same name. Here is codes: <input type="PASSWORD" name="password" defaultValue="3434" placeholder="Password" className="d-none" autoComplete="off" />   And please place this before redux form fields